# Formatting a particular sequence of text in a cell using vba

Tags: vba, excel

I have a situation in which I need few characters of a text sequence to have red color.

Eg. Text Sequence - `AAA 20.2%, BBB 23.3%, CCC 32.7%` and so on. 
In the text sequence I need only the percent values to be in red i.e. AAA "20.2%" in red, BBB "23.3%" in red, CCC "32.7%" in red

This sequence is obtained by doing vlookup i.e. the cell H4 has a vlookup formula through which I have obtained this sequence.
I have tried to change the color using the following VBA code but it isn't working as expected.

```
Public Function red_color(text As Range) As String
    Dim StartChar As Integer, LenColor As Integer
    'Dim result As String
    Dim regex As Object
    Set regex = CreateObject("VBScript.RegExp")
    Dim i As Integer
    i = 1

    With regex
        .Pattern = "d?"
    End With

    While Mid(text, InStr(i, text, "%"), 1) = "%"
        'Mid(text, instr(i, text, " ")+1, instr(i, text, ",")-1)
        StartChar = InStr(i, text, regex.Execute(text))
        LenColor = Len(Mid(text, InStr(i, text, " ") + 1, InStr(i, text, "%")))
        text.Characters(StartChar, LenColor).Font.Color = RGB(255, 0, 0)

        i = InStr(i, text, "%") + 1

   Wend
   'red_color = result
End Function
```

So the end result should be like `red_color(vlookup())` which will give me the output I need.

Comment: You will need a Sub to calculate and change the cell values, and use `range.Characters(Start,length).Font` to change color per cell.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot color the text in a cell like you're attempting if the cell has a formula.

This is a "fixed" version of your regex code, but you will need to add in some code to populate the cells.

```
Public Function red_color(c As Range) As String

    Dim regex As Object, matches, match
    Set regex = CreateObject("VBScript.RegExp")

    'here you need to calculate the cell content....

    c.Font.Color = vbBlack
    With regex
        .Global = True
        .Pattern = "(\d+\.?\d+\%)"
    End With

    Set matches = regex.Execute(c.text)

    For Each match In matches
        c.Characters(match.firstindex + 1, match.Length).Font.Color = RGB(255, 0, 0)
    Next match

End Function
```